# How to obtain coordinates of maximum density

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, gaussian

How could I get the coordinates of a point in the space with the greatest density.

[image]

I have this code to generate a random point and density analyze from this point.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(0., 10., N)

x_data = random_data(50)
y_data = random_data(50)

kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x_data, y_data]), bw_method=0.05)

b = plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'ro')
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x_data,"y":y_data})
p = sns.jointplot(data=df,x='x', y='y',kind='kde')

plt.show(p)
```

Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 2):

For starters, let me state the obvious by saying that `sns.jointplot` computes the kernel density on its own, so your `kernel` variable is as of yet unused.

Here's what `sns.jointplot` generated for me with a random sample:
[image: fancy 2d kernel density contour with marginal distributions]

There's a nice maximum at around (7, 5.4).

Here's what your `kernel` corresponds to:

```
x,y = np.mgrid[:10:100j, :10:100j]  # 100 x 100 grid for plotting
z = kernel.pdf(np.array([x.ravel(),y.ravel()])).reshape(x.shape)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=10)
ax.axis('scaled')
```

[image: output from original kernel's KDE: scattered sharp peaks around input points]

This will clearly not do: the density contains peaks centered around your input points; you will never be able to get a similar estimate than what `sns.jointplot` gave you.

We can easily fix this: you just have to drop the custom `bw_method` argument in the call to `gaussian_kde`:

```
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x_data, y_data]))

x,y = np.mgrid[:10:100j, :10:100j]  # 100 x 100 grid for plotting
z = kernel.pdf(np.array([x.ravel(),y.ravel()])).reshape(x.shape)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=10)
ax.axis('scaled')
```

This looks just the way you want it:
[image: fixed contour plot which looks like the one from sns.jointplot]

Now you know that this `kernel.pdf` is a bivariate function for which you're looking for the maximum.

And to find the maximum you should probably use something from [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), for instance [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) (the trick is to look at the negative of your function, which turns maxima into minima).

Since your function will probably have a few local maxima, finding the global maximum reliably is not trivial. I would either use the aforementioned `minimize`, but first use a sparse mesh over the relevant domain and find the best maximum candidate first, *or* use a heavy-weight solver such as [`differential_evolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#scipy.optimize.differential_evolution) which is a stochastic solver that's supposed to be good at finding the true global minimum of a function.

Root finding and minimization is always fickle business, so you will have to play around with your real data and available methods to find a reliable workflow that gives you your maximum.